# What's the UML syntax for multiplicity? ( inside the class box )

Tags: oop, uml, ooad

I know it is possible to specify the multiplicity within the same class box, without having to draw the link to another class.

My question is, Where should the multiplicity go, after the name or after the type?

Is it:

*visibility name multiplicity : type*

as

```
+ clients [0..n] : Client
```

or

*visibility name : type multiplicity*

as

```
+ clients : Client [0..n]
```

I have two books (Applitying UML and Patterns by Larman and UML and the Unified process by Arlow and Newstadt ) but they differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulled from printed page 107 of the [UML 2.2 Superstructure OMG Specificiation](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/09-02-02)

> Example ...
>
> +createWindow (location: Coordinates, container: Container **[0..1]**): Window

**MORE** Examples from the multiplicity element spec, on printed page 97.

Example from Spec on multiplicity.

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|                Customer                    |
|--------------------------------------------|
| purchase : Purchase [*] {ordered, unique}  |
| account: Account [0..5] {unique}           |
|                                            |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: That's the kind of reference I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

UML syntax is a diagrammatic syntax. See this multiplicity example from

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Figure 6: An example of a bi-directional association between a Flight class and a Plane class

```
 -----------------                   -----------------
 | Flight        |0..*         0..1  |  Plane        |
 |               | ------------------|               |
 |----------------                   -----------------
```