# How to indicate a list of types in a Class Diagram

Tags: list, uml, class-diagram

As the problem states, I am trying to indicate 'multiple' of a type in a Class Diagram- for example, my Class is a lecture:

```
Lecture

topic : String
lecturer : String
timeStart : Time
studentsAttending : **Insert indication of list of students here**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the UML syntax for multiplicity? ( inside the class box )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037757/whats-the-uml-syntax-for-multiplicity-inside-the-class-box)

Comment: Also note that this would be better expressed as a relation "attending" between `Lecture` and `Student` classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an association between Lecture and Student. On the student end of the association, create an association end called "studentsAttending" having a multiplicity of 0..*. (I recommend you call that association end "attendingStudent" to be consistent with standards such as ISO 11179, BTW.)

You should probably give the other end of the association a name also, like "attendedLecture", with a multiplicity of 0..*.

Here's an example:

[image: Example]

These association ends *are* properties, owned either by the class on the opposite side of the association or owned by the association. Here's some evidence of this from a UML 2 compliant tool:

[image]

When the max cardinality is > 1, the property typically gets a type that is some kind of collection in the technology. For an example in Java: `List<Student> attendingStudent`. (Although in the technology layer, I prefer to pluralize such properties, which would make that `List<Student> attendingStudents`.)

Comment: How do we represent list of strings?

Comment: Change `topic` to have multiplicity [1..*].