# (UML) What type of relationship is correct between class container that contains List<>, and class that stores in this List<> (look diagram)?

Tags: c#, list, class, uml, relationship

Please term the right type of relationship and explain your choice. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You have to explain more the relation between the entities, you also have to choose either the list or the product!

Comment: @YazidErman Product creates out of Container class. We add product to list only through `Add` method. Class 'Product' can be used in another classes too. List<> can stores many Products.

Comment: @YazidErman What do you mean - " you also have to choose either the list or the product"?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985491/how-to-indicate-a-list-of-types-in-a-class-diagram/33986115#33986115 .

Comment: @JimL.  If you don't mind, I need some explanations. Why didn't you show the 'dependence' or 'aggregation' relationship between those classes?  I think in that case, relationship could be expressed more concretely than simple 'association ' (Why you didn't show List<> of students in Lecture class?)

Comment: Why would you think any of that is necessary?

Comment: @JimL. If you will show more concretely type of dependency, the diagram will look more clear. Or I am wrong?

Comment: Actually, why do you have an add method for a 1:1 multiplicity? Add implies you will add to the product property, shown at the end of the association.

Comment: BTW, an one to one multiplicity usually indicates a mistake in the model.

Comment: Note that you have two properties containing Product types. As the linked answer tells you, that is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98941/discussion-between-evgeniy-miroshnichenko-and-jim-l).

Comment: Obviously, you need to set some order in your own thoughts. Start your question from a dictionary. Set all terms you want to speak about and their definitions, as you see them. After that formulate the question. Now you are lost in containers of containers.

Answer (score 2):

Your case is not clear enough yet, but According to my understanding and previous experience, I think you are taking the modeling to a lower level by adding the list type here! We would simply say that a container consists of n products, and in this case a composition or aggregation relation between the two classes will do the job, basing on this fact, we will have a foreign key inside the products db table indicating the container, the list concept would maybe needed in the code level not the database level.
In brief, the first diagram is accepted, just add n instead of 1, and make it composition if the container is nothing without products in it.